# Define converter in xaml with parameter(s)

Tags: .net, xaml, converters

At the start of my xaml page I define converters like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <l:MyMagicConverter x:Key="magicConverter"/>
  </Grid.Resources>
```

Is there a way to add some parameter for the converter to this definition? Like a DependencyProperty, or maybe something simpler? Something like this:

```
    <l:MyMagicConverter x:Key="magicConverter" MyParameter="{Binding MyValue}"/>
```

I'm aware of the converterparameter when using it, but I'd like to add something in the definition, too.

Answer (score 2):

One can add properties to the converter and then access them in Xaml.

```
public class RadioButtonToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string ABC { get; set; }
```

Xaml:

```
<reportConverters:RadioButtonToIntConverter x:Key="RadioButtonToIntConverter" 
                                            ABC="def" />
```

Now what you are binding it to, as to a static resource may be a problem.

---

As an aside, if one does not want to have to *directly* instantiate the converter in xaml, I provide a way to automatically hook up a converter without that xaml instantiation.

[Xaml: Call Binding Converter Without Defining StaticResource in Xaml Thanks to Markup Derived Base Class in C#](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1000)

I suggest this as a way to instantiate the target converter which has 'pre-baked' properties which you might want to use.